# Database and tools for synchronize data between embedded computers in "real time"

Tags: mysql, database, embedded, real-time, synchronize

I have 3 Beagleboards that needs to share data between each other as fast as possible. They are running debian (with a real time kernel) and are connected to each other via wlan.

All beagleboards have different sensors attached. All Beagleboards need the sensor data of the others in real time (or at least as fast as possible -the data are used in control algorithms for actuators).

The system is supposed to be used for demonstrate a concept and does not need to be 100% fault proof but as close as possible.

What is the best way to design such a system?

Ideas:
Design program for UDP broadcast and some sql server or just an object/class on the receiver end.

Embedded MySQL/High Performance MySQL with replication or cluster.

SQLite - need some addons?

Any other solutions might be better, I have never designed such a system before. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If "as fast as possible" is your requirement you need to do the sharing of data yourself and use the database just to store shared data.

You can implement a publisher / subscriber mechanism. One of your nodes becomes master and each of other nodes subbscribes to this node at startup. Master node multiplies and routes messages from subscribers.

Another (faster) option is implementing the publisher / subscriber mechanism without a master node. Each node registers itself to other nodes, it is similar to broadcasting you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After talking to some experts I've decided to use zeromq (zeromq.org) for communication and some small key-value pair on-memory database.